# How to echo last word after / of a link (url)

Tags: php

supposing i send to someone  http://www.test.com/?m=Name  as my url and I want to display the last word "Name"  to one who opens the link.
Please some one help me out with required script thx..

Comment: Are you writing a CGI script, or is this in an IM or email or talk or ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160382/how-do-i-grab-all-parameters-from-a-url-and-print-it-out-in-php

Comment: I haven't touched PHP in a while, but accessing the GET parameters is so basic a thing to do that you're likely to find it in _any_ tutorial. So, maybe we should just asked if you've already tried to do something, or are you just asking us to write that for you? (And yeah, this is off-topic, should be on stackoverflow, but you'd get downvoted there, too)

Answer (score 1):

Try below php code for display url parameters in php script :

```
    <?php
      echo $_GET['m'];
    ?>
```

OR

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['m']);
```